# subtitle or titleaddon: which to choose?

Tags: biblatex

### Question

In my `.bib` file, I want to add a book that has a "main" and a "subsidiary" title.

**Which field should I use for the subsidiary title: `titleaddon` or `subtitle`?** ([The `biblatex` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is not clear enough on that point for me - cf. §2.2.2 on page 23.)
What is the difference between the two in practice?

---

### Example

[image]

Considering previous book, which of following entry is the most indicated (changes in the penultimate line only) ?

```
@Book{Williams2002,
 Title                    = {Free as in Freedom},
 Author                   = {Williams, Sam},
 Publisher                = {O'Reilly Media},
 Year                     = {2002},
 ISBN                     = {0-596-00287-4},
 Titleaddon               = {Richard Stallman's Crusade for Free Software}
}
```

or

```
@Book{Williams2002,
 Title                    = {Free as in Freedom},
 Author                   = {Williams, Sam},
 Publisher                = {O'Reilly Media},
 Year                     = {2002},
 ISBN                     = {0-596-00287-4},
 Subtitle                 = {Richard Stallman's Crusade for Free Software}
}
```

Comment: The difference in output is that the `subtitle` will be treated like `title` (i.e. it is also in italics/quotes) and separated from `title` by `\subtitlepunct`. `titleaddon` has its own format (normally plain, I believe) and is separated by the standard `\newunit`. The idea is that `titleaddon` gives non-essential information about the work, in `biblatex-examples.bib` that is often something like "Proceedings of the ...". In this case I'm tempted to say it is a `subtitle`, but what do I know ...

Comment: The [`biblatex-chicago` doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf) mentions `titleaddon` quite a bit, maybe that can give you a feel. I feel that `titleaddon` is more of a meta field while `subtitle` is on the same level as `title`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The main difference between `subtitle` and `titleaddon` is the presentation in the bibliography. While `subtitle` is set in the same style as the title and connected by a special `\subtitlepunct`, `titleaddon` is (by default, you can of course change that) set in normal font. This can make one feel that `titleaddon` is not as closely connected to the title as `subtitle`.

Indeed in `biblatex-examples.bib` you will find `titleaddon` used to add a description like "Proceedings of the ...". The example files to `biblatex-chicago` use `titleaddon` either as a replacement for a proper title or to provide additional information such as "review of ..." or "interview with ...".

All in all, I would say that the `titleaddon` is often used in a "meta" capacity to give additional information or to replacing a missing title. `subtitle` on the other hand is mostly on the same level as `title`.

In your case then, I would probably go for `subtitle`, but that is just my gut feeling.